# How to disable post specific comment feed?

Tags: wordpress, feed, yoast, rss2

Wordpress is automatically creating post-specific comment feed such as

http://example.com/post-name/feed/

I want to disable this functionality. How can I achieve it?

Is this something related to Yoast SEO plugin? If yes, then what’ should I change in settings?

Answer (score 0):

On the post, click screen options on the top and find the comment status. From here, you should be able to this off when it displays in the meta-box below.

Comment: Hi, I tried but couldn’t solve by this method. Is this something related to Yoast SEO settings? I am also using an RSS feed plugin. Are there any chances that either of these plugins creating these feeds?